# Seg Fault Error :11 Known lines with Error

Tags: c, malloc, token, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a seg fault error in this piece of code, however I do not understand why. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong. 
I have commented the list of things I need to do in this function. I thought I was doing it right however when I print it out it turns out something totally different is actually happening.

```
void analyze_file(FILE *file, struct climate_info **states, int num_states) {
    const int line_sz = 100;
    char line[line_sz];
    int currentStates = countStates(states);

    while (fgets(line, line_sz, file) != NULL) 
    {

        char* foundCode = strtok(line, "\t");                   
        int rankOfState = compareOrder(states, foundCode, currentStates);
        if(rankOfState == -1)             
        {

            states[currentStates] = (struct climate_info *) malloc(sizeof(struct climate_info) *num_states);
            strcpy((states[currentStates]) -> code, foundCode);
            states[currentStates] -> num_records=1;

            char* currentTimeStamp = strtok(NULL, "\t");                    
            unsigned long TIMESTAMP;
            sscanf(currentTimeStamp,"%lu", &TIMESTAMP);                        


            char* currentGeol = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            long long GEOL;
            sscanf(currentGeol,"%llu", &GEOL);


            char* currentHumidity = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            double HUMIDITY;
            sscanf(currentHumidity, "%lf",&HUMIDITY);


            char* currentSnow = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            float SNOW;
            sscanf(currentSnow, "%f", &SNOW);


            char* currentCloud = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            double CLOUD;
            sscanf(currentCloud, "%lf",&CLOUD);


            char* currentLightning = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            float LIGHTNING;
            sscanf(currentLightning, "%f", &LIGHTNING);


            char* currentPressure = strtok(NULL,"\t");
            double PRESSURE;
            sscanf(currentPressure, "%lf", &PRESSURE);



            char* currentTemp = strtok(NULL, "\t\n"); 

            double TEMP;
            sscanf(currentTemp, "%lf",&TEMP);


            if (TEMP < states[currentStates]->lo_temp_reading || states[currentStates]->lo_temp_timestamp == 0)
            {
                states[currentStates]->lo_temp_reading = TEMP;
                states[currentStates]->lo_temp_timestamp = TIMESTAMP;
            }
            if (TEMP > states[currentStates]->hi_temp_reading || states[currentStates]->hi_temp_timestamp == 0)
            {
                states[currentStates]->hi_temp_reading = TEMP;
                states[currentStates]->hi_temp_timestamp = TIMESTAMP;
            }

            currentStates++;
        }
        else
        {                                                
            (*(states +rankOfState))->num_records +=1;

            char* currentTimeStamp = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            unsigned long TIMESTAMP;
            sscanf(currentTimeStamp,"%lu", &TIMESTAMP);


            char* currentGeol = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            (*(states +rankOfState))->hi_millitime += *currentGeol;

            char* currentHumidity = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            double HUMIDITY;
            sscanf(currentHumidity, "%lf",&HUMIDITY);
            (*(states +rankOfState))->humidity += HUMIDITY;

            char* currentSnow = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            float SNOW;
            sscanf(currentSnow, "%f", &SNOW);
            (*(states +rankOfState))->snow += SNOW;

            char* currentCloud = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            double CLOUD;
            sscanf(currentCloud, "%lf",&CLOUD);
            (*(states +rankOfState))->cloud += CLOUD;

            char* currentLightning = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            float LIGHTNING;
            sscanf(currentLightning, "%f", &LIGHTNING);
            (*(states +rankOfState))->lightning += LIGHTNING;

            char* currentPressure = strtok(NULL,"\t");
            double PRESSURE;
            sscanf(currentPressure, "%lf", &PRESSURE);
            (*(states +rankOfState))->pressure += PRESSURE;

            char* currentTemp = strtok(NULL, "\t\n");
            double TEMP;
            sscanf(currentTemp, "%lf",&TEMP);

            (*(states +rankOfState))->temperature += TEMP;

            if (TEMP <= states[currentStates]->lo_temp_reading)
            {
                states[currentStates]->lo_temp_reading = TEMP;
                states[currentStates]->lo_temp_timestamp = *currentTimeStamp;
            }
            else if (*currentTemp > states[currentStates]->hi_temp_reading)
            {
                states[currentStates]->hi_temp_reading = *currentTemp;
                states[currentStates]->hi_temp_timestamp = *currentTimeStamp;
            }

            currentStates++;
        }
    }
}
```

And if I comment out these lines, my output prints however, it only analyzes one line.

```
if (TEMP <= states[currentStates]->lo_temp_reading)
{
    states[currentStates]->lo_temp_reading = TEMP;
    states[currentStates]->lo_temp_timestamp = *currentTimeStamp;
}
else if (*currentTemp > states[currentStates]->hi_temp_reading)
{
   states[currentStates]->hi_temp_reading = *currentTemp;
   states[currentStates]->hi_temp_timestamp = *currentTimeStamp;
}
```

Here is are the helper functions I used:

```
int compareOrder(struct climate_info **states, char codex[3], int currentStates)          //returns the order of each state in the array
{
    int order = 0;
    while (order < currentStates)          //while order is less than number of states analyzed
    {
        if(strcmp((states[order])->code, codex) == 0)       //if the states is present
        {
            return order;
        }
        order++;                                                //increment here to check every line for when to update state codes
    }
    return -1;                                                  //returns -1 the state is not prsent in struct
}


int countStates(struct climate_info **states)                           //function to count number of states present
{
    int num = 0;
    while(num < 50 && states[num] != NULL)
    {
        num++;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer if you posted an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The signature of your `countStates` function looks suspicious. My personal impression is that it would iterate over the array until finding the first null pointer. But as you don't pass in `num_states` as parameter, how do you make sure that the function won't iterate past the end of the array?

Comment: Why do you increment currentStates in the else branch? You do create any new data, this does not look right.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct climate_info) * num_states);`: if `num_states` is *not* the length of `states` array, how do you detect the latter's end then? Or are you trying to create a `n*n` array? If your final goal is just having an array of pointers to single structs, then you are `malloc`-ing too much memory, `malloc(sizeof(struct climate_info))` suffices. Be aware that this won't lead to failure, you're just *wasting* memory.

Comment: Just a matter of style: Avoid all-upper-case variable names, these are usually (by convention) used for constants (`#define SOME_THING 1012`), sometimes for enum members as well (but these are constants, too...).

Comment: @Aconcagua what's your email, I feel it would be easier if I sent you the rest, so you could get a better understanding/

Comment: I incremented current states in a separate function yes, however I believe my error is that im not pointing to the correct variable.

Comment: @JustAJAVAGUY What you actually should do is creating a [mcve] (as nemequ stated already), so *anybody* could help you. Minimality: Throw away anything from your code that does not produce the error (most likely the snow/cloud/... assignments; of course you should maintain a copy of to restore the code as soon as the error is found...). While doing so, chances are that you find the error yourself. About completeness: Add the code of `countStates` and `compareOrder` functions, additionally the context of the call to `analyze_file (*how* it is called).

Comment: @Aconcagua I have included the helper functions

Comment: `const int line_sz = 100; char line[line_sz];` uses a C99 feature, VLA. Just FYI - `const int` is not a constant, unlike a macro.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ... and unlike C++...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your code, unfortunately, there's quite a lot of information missing, so this answer is based on assumptions.

***Edit:*** OK, this part got obsolete with your latest edit of the question; still: the signature proposed is supperior as it does not rely on the hard coded maximum array length, which you additionally provided as 'magic number'...

At first, `countStates` function; I assume it looks more or less as follows:

```
size_t countStates(struct climate_info** states)
{
    struct climate_info** end = states;
    while(*end)
        ++end;
    return end - states;
}
```

Problem now is that you could easily iterate beyond the array bounds, causing undefined behaviour and possily crash already in this function. To fix, total array size/length as well:

```
size_t countStates(struct climate_info** states, size_t length)
{
    struct climate_info** end = states;
    while(length-- && *end)
        ++end;
    return end - states;
}
```

Then let's get to the actual function (don't wonder about changed formatting/syntax, it is equivalent if not denoted otherwise – these are my personal preferences...):

```
// (size_t is more appropriate than int here...)
void analyze_file(FILE* file, struct climate_info* states[], size_t num_states)
{
    const size_t line_sz = 100;
    char line[line_sz];
    size_t currentStates = countStates(states, num_states);

    while (fgets(line, line_sz, file) != NULL) 
    {
        char* foundCode = strtok(line, "\t");                   
        int rankOfState = compareOrder(states, foundCode, currentStates);
        if(rankOfState == -1)             
        {
            // new states available at all?
            if(currentStates == num_states)
            {
                 // some appropriate error handling - need to decide you!
                 // for now, just returning from function:
                 return;
            }

            // just allocate one struct (assumption): 
            states[currentStates] = (struct climate_info *) malloc(sizeof(struct climate_info));

            // always check the result of malloc!
            if(!states[currentStates])
            {
                 // allocation failed, no memory available on OS!!!
                 // some appropriate error handling - need to decide you!
                 // for now, just returning from function:
                 return;
            }

            // prefer strncpy to assure you don't copy past the end!
            // sure, it will fill overdue bytes with 0, but still we are safer
            // (assumption: climate_info contains an array!)
            strncpy(states[currentStates]->code, foundCode, sizeof(states[currentStates]->code));
            states[currentStates]->num_records = 1;

            // ...

            // now you created a new struct with malloc; be aware
            // that memory is uninitialized and could contain *ANY*
            // data, reading uninitialized memory is undefined behaviour!
            //if (TEMP < states[currentStates]->lo_temp_reading || states[currentStates]->lo_temp_timestamp == 0)
            //{
                states[currentStates]->lo_temp_reading = TEMP;
            //    states[currentStates]->lo_temp_timestamp = TIMESTAMP;
            //}
            //if (TEMP > states[currentStates]->hi_temp_reading || states[currentStates]->hi_temp_timestamp == 0)
            //{
                states[currentStates]->hi_temp_reading = TEMP;
                states[currentStates]->hi_temp_timestamp = TIMESTAMP;
            //}
            // (it's a new set anyway, so just set the values...)

            currentStates++;
        }
        else
        {                                                
            ++states[rankOfState]->num_records; // just a little bit simpler...

            // ...

            states[rankOfState]->temperature += TEMP;

            if (TEMP <= states[currentStates]->lo_temp_reading)
            {
                states[currentStates]->lo_temp_reading = TEMP;
                states[currentStates]->lo_temp_timestamp = *currentTimeStamp;
            }
            // this should not have resulted in crash, but assign a bad value!
            else if (TEMP /* *currentTemp */ > states[currentStates]->hi_temp_reading)
            {
                states[currentStates]->hi_temp_reading = TEMP /* *currentTemp */;
                states[currentStates]->hi_temp_timestamp = *currentTimeStamp;
            }
            // same for timestamp in both branches: you don't want to assign first character of string,
            // but the parsed value (e. g. 1012, if string was "1012", *... would deliver 49
            // (ASCII code of character `1`; assuming you have ASCII compatible encoding)

            // wrong in this branch: you did NOT add a new element
            //currentStates++;
        }
    }
}
```

As indicated already: This is based on what I *think* you are trying to do. Leave a comment if my assumptions are wrong...